# Change bash script to append 0s to reach a certain line number

Tags: bash, average

I have this command line that calculates average, standard deviation, median, min value and max value.

```
cut -f3 $file | sort -n | awk 'BEGIN {c = 0; sum = 0;} $1 ~ /^(\-)?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {a[c++] = $1; sum += $1; sumsq+=$1*$1} END {ave = sum / c; if( (c % 2) == 1 ) { median = a[ int(c/2) ]; } else {median = ( a[c/2] + a[c/2-1] ) / 2; } OFS="\t"; sd = sqrt(sumsq/c - (sum/c)**2); print ave, sd, median, a[0], a[c-1]; }' >> $output
```

Each file has millions of lines, that should adds up to exactly 772,474,283.
But many files don't, and if they don't this biases the statistics I want to calculate.
I should thus add 0 values(after having cut the third column) so that the total line number adds up to this number and that the zeros are taken into account while calculating the average, sd, etc.

I guess I should calculate line number on my file with wc -l and then appends X zeroes, with X=772,474,283-line number?
How can I do that?

Or do you know a more elegant way?

Thanks!

M

Comment: This condition of necessiting a specific number of lines seems to be not very... practical. Can't you instead get rid of it ?

Comment: Since producing a set of n identical lines is trivial (using something like `yes 0 | head -n $n`, I would go for it. A more serious problem seems to me in the logic of your calculation: Since you calculate `sum/c`, where c obviously is integer, then either `sum`is also integer, in which the quotient gets truncated to integer (wrong resurlt), or that `sum` is float, in which case `sum += $1` implies adding to float numbers, which in general gives incorrect results.

Comment: cramming your code onto 1 line doesn't help you (or us) to be able to debug a problem with it. [edit] your question to show your code formatted legibly so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calculate line number on my file with wc -l and then appends X zeroes, with X=772,474,283-line number? How can I do that?

something like this

```
min=772474283    # a billion lines really?

cut3min() {
    [ $# -lt 1 ] && return
    f="$1"; shift
    cut -f3 "$f"
    n=$(wc -l <"$f")
    [ "$n" -ge "$min" ] && return
    for ((i=$n; i<$min; i++)) { echo 0; }
}

# cut -f3 "$file" | ...
cut3min "$file" | ...
```

but it's a shell, so it will be very slow if you process billions of lines

that simple loop+maths is better to be written in a language like C

Comment: Thanks, this works! And yes I work on files of billions lines ahah!